# How to make this loading animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, css, canvas, raphael

[image: Loading Animation Image]

I got the task of making an loading page for a webapp, based on the image above. The animation is basically the circle being filled from the left side to the right side, both in a clockwise and anti-clockwise way, but I have no idea how to do such animation. =/

Could someone give me a light on how to do this? It may be using canvas (I'll use the library Raphael.js), CSS (CSS3 Animations), or even just images (animating then with javascript).

Comment: Could you elaborate slightly on how it will get filled? Does the clockwise/anticlockwise spreading of the yellow start from a central line and somehow spread, or does the colour just gradually start to pass across from the left?

Comment: @oil The circle appears first in gray, then according to the percentage, the yellow layer will appear from the left, consuming the circle in both clockwise and counterclockwise (You can follow the arrows to see the evolution of the layer in yellow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with the canvas element and some sort of bezier curve animation, but it may be just as well to do it with images (and certainly easier). A large sprite of PNG frames could handle this easily and it wouldn't be that large of an image. Even better, since the top and bottom mirror each other, you could make the images for just the top, and then duplicate the element and flip it (with CSS transformations) to make the bottom half.